# LinkedIn API calling in Javascript

Tags: linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi

I have used the LinkedIn Javascript API calls in my html page. I can see the "Sign In With LinkedIn" button . In "onLinkedInLoad" function calling the "IN.Event.on("IN", "auth", onLinkedInAuth);" is not firing. I have an alert message 'call2' in my code and its also not calling.

Basically I want to read a company updates and bind into a div. In Browser console I am getting the below URL and profile's response. There is no other request in browser console.

https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people::(~):(id,first-name,last-name,headline,picture-url)

I followed all the instructions in LinkedIn document before doing this to consume a company update.

1. I have a company page and with an update.
2. I have created an app and use that api key only in js function call.
3. In LinkedIn REST Console I can see my update.

Do I miss anything ? Thanks.

I use the actual api key and company id at my end.

See my code :

```
<html>
<head>
<title>
    LinkedIn
</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
    api_key: 0000000000000
    onLoad: onLinkedInLoad
    authorize: true
</script>


<script type="text/javascript">
    function onLinkedInLoad() {
        alert('call');
        IN.Event.on("IN", "auth", onLinkedInAuth);
    }


    function onLinkedInAuth() {
        alert('call2');
        IN.API.Raw("/companies/000000/updates")
        .method("GET")
        .result(function(res) {
           document.write(JSON.stringify(res));});
        }

</script>
</head>
<body>
  <script type="IN/Login">
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used IN.User.authorize(onLinkedInAuth) instead of IN.Event.on("IN", "auth", onLinkedInAuth) for authorization and worked.